# Can I get symbol name by "GOT address"?

Tags: linux, binary, elf, readelf, got

Now I'm developing program like `readelf` using `pyelftools` libraries.

I want to print the table like below.
In here, `Offset` field is `stderr@GOT` address.

```
jiwon@jiwon$ readelf -a --wide libstdbuf.so
...
Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x454 contains 12 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type                Sym. Value  Symbol's Name
00001c50  00000206 R_386_GLOB_DAT         00000000   stderr@GLIBC_2.0
...
```

Assume that I have only GOT address(`00001c50`) of unknown symbol.

***My situation*** I want to make function like `get_symname_by_GOTaddress` for resolution from *`00001c50`* to *`stderr@GLIBC_2.0`*.

***Question :*** However, I could not find any linkage information between `GOT address` and `symbol name` in binary. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every entry in the `.rel.dyn` section has at least the following fields:

```
r_offset;
r_info;
```

So first scan the section until the address match an entry's `r_offset` field, then field `r_info` contains (also) the index to the symbol table, which is composed according to this:

```
/* for 32bit */
#define ELF32_R_INFO(sym, type)       (((sym)<<8)+(unsigned char)(type))

/* for 64bit */
#define ELF64_R_INFO(sym, type)       (((Elf64_Xword)(sym)<<32)+ \ 
                                        (Elf64_Xword)(type))
```

So you can extract the `sym` index, then fetch the entry from the symbol table, which has the field `st_name`, which is the index into the string table, which contains the symbol name in characters representation.

Links for more information:

[rel.dyn section description](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-54839.html) -> [symbol table description](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/chapter6-79797/index.html) -> [string table description](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-73709.html)